# JTDS: Unicode parameters using CallableStatement with sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false

Tags: java, sql-server, unicode, jtds

We have encountered the performance issues described in the JTDS documentation regarding index scans (SQL Server 2000 and upwards), and have therefore had to set the `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` parameter to `false`.

This is fine for 99.9% of our cases, however, we have an application that does rely on unicode data in an ntext field. We write to the aforementioned table using a stored procedure, which has an NTEXT parameter. Since changing the above setting, our unicode strings are translated to '?' characters, which is not particularly useful.

I have fiddled with various things, including:

- `setObject(1, unicode_string, Types.NCLOB); //as well as NVARCHAR`
- `stmt.setUnicodeStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(unicode_string.getBytes("UTF16")), unicode_string.length());`
- `setNClob(1, unicode_string);`

None of these however work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround (though its not the correct answer), is to use a **Statement** rather than a **CallableStatement**:

```
stmt = cn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO test_unicode (my_unicode) VALUES (N'" + input + "')");
```

This is however presents a significant performance overhead.